# How to use size_t as a member function in c++?

Tags: c++

I was asked to create a function in c++. In the header file the function should look like this:

```
namespace w3 {
    class Text {
    public:
        size_t size() const;
    }
}
```

This function should return the number of record of text data from a file.

I've searched all over and I can't find a simple way of implementing a function like this. How do I implement a function like this? Its my first time using size_t and all the examples I've seen its been used IN functions and not AS functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: size_t is an unsigned integer over 64 bits.. it's just a number.

Comment: @Roberto So I'll use it the same way I would use an int or char?

Comment: @Mekanic Yes. This would be completely valid: `size_t size() const { return 4; }`

Comment: @Mekanic, exactly!

Comment: Oh ok... I guess its just a matter of the type of number size_t will return then?

Comment: It is not used "as function" in your code. It is used as *function return type*.

Comment: Great. Thanks guys.

Comment: @AnT • if it was `operator size_t() const { return 4; }` it could be used "as function" of sorts... but that would be not something I'd recommend in practice (eww, ick ick, ptui).

Comment: @Eljay Thanks also.

Comment: @RobertoTrani — `size_t` can be smaller than 64 bits. Its size is system- and compiler-dependent.

Comment: [Documentation on `size_t`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) It is an interesting beast, despite having yet to appear in a Harry Potter novel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is "text record". I believe you're expected to implement a class that is able to read and store some collection of data. Once your class has a container storing your records that have been read from a file, you will be able to easily provide size() implementation, like

```
class MyData {
   std::vector<MyDataRecord> records;
...........
   public:
   size_t size() {return records.size();}
...........
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to respond @Andrey. I haven't learnt how to use vectors as yet unfortunately but I will research your answer.

Comment: @Andrew, you was right, had to use vectors. Just that I didn't learn it as yet but I guess I have to learn it now.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is just another type. On my computer for example it's exactly the same as `unsigned long` (but on yours it might be `unsigned int` for example; it's allowed to be different on different platforms).

So you can use it exactly the same way as (for example) `int` or `char`.